# Rails 6 does not see JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I created new application. Installed bootstrap, jquery, popper via `yarn add`.
Imported bootstrap `.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` (and styles works fine).

Found problem with js.
It seems like Rails does not see js at all.

What I did already: tried to `import bootstrap` and add simple jquery code into `app/assets/javascript/packs/application.js`, `app/assets/javascript/application.js`. Tried to create `custom.js` and require it in both `application.js`
Changed `javascript_tag` in layout.
I tried all recommendations from tutorials.

Everything without success. I have a hunch that somewhere js already accidentally compiled and any my edits in `application.js` useless for app. Is it possible?

I starting app in development mode via foreman Proc file.

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us the actual `application.js` and the file you are importing? Its impossible to give any kind of meaningful debugging help without a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 6 uses webpacker to bundle JS code by default. So JS is not bundles throught the asset pipeline anymore (it used to live in `app/assets/javascript`. The new folder lives directly under `app`, so: `app/javascript`. Also you require JS now with the `javascript_pack_tag`!

Read more here: https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/

If you want to make bootstrap work (and you already installed it via yarn), import it in `app/javascript/application.js`

```
import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Omg, I'm so blind. I didn't notice javascript directory in app and did changes in assets. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are some dependencies, which you have to add to make things work. I could write every step down, but there is a nice tutorial, which will walk you through step by step:
[Add Bootstrap 4 to your Ruby on Rails 6 application](https://www.mashrurhossain.com/blog/rails6bootstrap4)